# camera following character in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have a character called _player mc that moves when the mouse is clicked. I need it so that when i click the camera moves with the character. ( I don't want it so that the stage moves) I have searched everywhere but couldn't find it. how would i go about doing this? this is my code.

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;

public class Main extends MovieClip {
    // player

    public var _player:MovieClip;

    // player settings
    private var _playerSpeed:Number = 10;

    // other vars
    private var _destinationX:int;
    private var _destinationY:int;

    //box
    private var boxAmount:Number=0;
    private var boxLimit:Number=20;
    private var _root:Object;
    //$txt
    public var money:int=0;
    public var gold:int=0;
    public var my_scrollbar:MakeScrollBar;

    //$$
    public var testnumber:Number = 1;



    public function Main() {

        $box.click$.move$.buttonMode=true;
        $box.click$.clickmini$.buttonMode=true;




createPlayer();


        // add listeners
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler);


        //box add listener
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);

        //moneybox
        $box.click$.move$.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startmoving$);
        $box.click$.move$.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopmoving$);
        $box.click$.clickmini$.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, c$mini);

        my_scrollbar=new MakeScrollBar(scroll_mc,scroll_text);



    }
        private function createPlayer():void
    {
        _destinationX = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        _destinationY = stage.stageHeight / 2;

        _player = new Player();
        _player.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        _player.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        stage.addChild(_player);
    }


    private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        _player.x += (_destinationX - _player.x) / _playerSpeed;
        _player.y += (_destinationY - _player.y) / _playerSpeed;
    }


    private function mouseHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        _destinationX = event.stageX;
        _destinationY = event.stageY;

        rotatePlayer();
    }

    private function rotatePlayer():void
    {
        var radians:Number = Math.atan2(_destinationY - _player.y, _destinationX - _player.x);
        var degrees:Number = radians / (Math.PI / 180) + 90;
        _player.rotation = degrees;
    }





    //boxadding
    private function eFrame(event:Event):void {
        if (boxAmount<=boxLimit) {
            boxAmount++;

            var _box:Box=new Box  ;
            _box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,boxclick);
            _box.buttonMode=true;
            _box.y=Math.random()*stage.stageHeight;

            _box.x=Math.random()*stage.stageWidth;

            addChild(_box);

        }

    }

    public function boxclick(event:MouseEvent):void {
        var _box:Box=event.currentTarget as Box;
        logtxt.appendText("You collected " + testnumber +  " boxes" );
        _destinationX = _box.y + 40 + (_player.height / 2);
        _destinationY = _box.x;


        logtxt.scrollV=logtxt.maxScrollV;
        var randVal$:Number=Math.random();
        if (randVal$>=0.49) {
            money+=100;
        } else if (randVal$ <= 0.50 && randVal$ >= 0.15) {
            money+=200;
        } else if (randVal$ <= 0.14 && randVal$ >= 0.02) {
            gold+=10;
        } else if (randVal$ == 0.01) {
            money+=200;
            gold+=20;
        }


            testnumber ++;



        boxAmount--;


        $box.box$in.box$insins.Moneytxt.text=String(money);
        $box.box$in.box$insins.Goldtxt.text=String(gold);
        removeChild(_box);

    }

    private function startmoving$(event:MouseEvent):void {
        $box.startDrag();
    }
    private function stopmoving$(event:MouseEvent):void {
        $box.stopDrag();
    }
    private function c$mini(event:MouseEvent):void {
        $box.click$.move$.visible=false;
        $box.box$in.visible=false;

        $box.y=200;
        $box.x=100;
        $box.click$.clickmini$.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reclickbox$);
        $box.click$.clickmini$.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, c$mini);


    }
    private function reclickbox$(event:MouseEvent):void {
        $box.click$.clickmini$.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, c$mini);
        $box.click$.clickmini$.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reclickbox$);
        $box.y=70;
        $box.x=250;
        $box.click$.move$.visible=true;
        $box.box$in.visible=true;
    }

    public function scroll_text( n:Number ) {

        logtxt.scrollV = Math.round( ( logtxt.maxScrollV - 1 ) * n ) + 1;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a holder for all the assets: background, enemies, player.

When for example the player walks to the right move the main holder to the left. That way the background and everything in it will scroll to the left, but your player moves to the right and the player will visually remain in the center of the screen.

So your holder and the player will have opposite speeds:

```
player.x += speed;
holder.x -= speed;
```

This is what i mean:

[image: Example of game]

Comment: but I am trying to make a interactive game with the more than one person.

Comment: With person you mean for example enemies? I've edited my answer.

Comment: i mean another person as in a mmo

Comment: @thor625 - rather than just leaving a message saying you worked out the answer then leave, it's good etiquette on our site to leave an answer explaining how you solved the problem and upvote those who made an effort to help you. Please flag your question to be re-opened if you wish to do this.Thanks.